# Notice: Undefined index: uploadedfile Warning: getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty

Tags: php, getimagesize, image-file

I tried to use getimagesize function and i got those errors :
Notice: Undefined index: uploadedfile
Warning: getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty

form

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="uploadedfile" />
</form>
```

and script

```
$imageinfo = getimagesize($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']);
if($imageinfo['mime'] != 'image/gif' && $imageinfo['mime'] != 'image/gif') {
echo "Sorry, we only accepg GIF images";
exit;
}
```

what is wrong?
thanks.

Comment: Please show us your form tags, do you have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` set?

Comment: $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'] <------- that's empty

Comment: Yes I have enctype set.

Comment: Try to remove name="uploadedfile" from <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="uploadedfile" /> ... you have the same name on the input.

Comment: You can't have 2 input types with the same name, also put a if statement around your script: `if(!empty($_FILES['uploadedfile'])) {`

Comment: I did remove name="uploadedfile" and nothing changed

Comment: Where do you check that `$_FILES` is not empty (that is, that anything has been posted)? If you run this code before verifying that anything has been submitted, then you risk attempting to use nonexistent data. In this case, `$_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']` is not set, so the most likely explanation is that the form wasn't submitted when you got this error.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check your php.ini file to see if the max file size is set to a value that will accept your file. e.g.

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 2000M
```